# Arduino Sketch - Object in header file not containing any values

Tags: arrays, arduino, header-files

I have the following in `Codes.h`, which I access by clicking on the tab within the Arduino Software. So I know the sketch is being loaded properly with the header file.

```
#ifndef __CODES_H__
#define __CODES_H__

PROGMEM prog_uint16_t show_hide_info[] = { 4216, 8900, 4380, 580, 500, 600, 500, 580, 1620, 580, 500, 600, 500, 580, 500, 600, 480, 600, 500, 580, 1620, 580, 1620, 600, 500, 580, 1620, 580, 1620, 600, 1600, 600, 1620, 580, 1620, 600, 500, 580, 1620, 580, 500, 600, 1600, 600, 500, 580, 1620, 580, 500, 600, 1620, 580, 1620, 600, 480, 600, 1620, 580, 500, 600, 1600, 600, 500, 580, 1620, 580, 500, 600, 39300, 8860, 2160, 580 };

#endif
```

I then have in my code a method that uses the `show_hide_info[]` array.

The problem is that when I try to access the array in the header file it doesn't contain any values.

Instead if I declare the above `PROGMEM` above the `setup()` method it does contain values.

Not quite sure why I'm getting this problem. I can confirm I've declared my header file properly by doing the following in my sketch.

`#include "Codes.h"`

This is an example of how I use the array:

```
void sendCode(prog_uint16_t inArray[], int nLimit) {
  unsigned int arr[nLimit];
  unsigned int c;
  int index = 0;

  while ((c = pgm_read_word(inArray++))) {
    arr[index] = c;
    index++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < nLimit; i=i+2) {
    Serial.println(arr[i]);
    Serial.println(arr[i+1]);
  }
}
```

Nothing outputs in the console if I try to use the array in the header file. It only works if I declare it within my actual main sketch program.

I know it's not a problem with the array itself or my method as a simple string or int does not work either. Very strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines works for me:

At the top of your sketch, simply:

```
#include "Codes.h"
```

`Codes.h` needs to look like this to work:

```
#ifndef __CODES_H__
#define __CODES_H__

// Implicitly includes <avr/pgmspace.h> to provide access to progmem features
#include <Arduino.h>

// Split up declaration and definition to remove warning
extern const prog_uint16_t show_hide_info[] PROGMEM;
const prog_uint16_t show_hide_info[] = { 
  4216, 8900, 
  4380, 580, 
  500, 600, 
  500, 580, 
  1620, 580, 
  /* and so on... */
  0 // Need this to prevent sendCode reading beyond the end of this array
};

#endif
```

Comment: I had to include <avr/pgmspace.h> within my sketch and that was pretty much the only modification I had to make. Everything works perfectly now. Thanks.